# R element wise subtraction of matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have two 1-column matrices of different lengths.  Both matrices have row names in common and other row names that are unique to each (and the may not be in the same order).  How do I subtract the two making sure that each common element is subtracted from each other?  for instance:

```
> mat1
  [,1]
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
e    5
f    6

> mat2
  [,1]
x    1
a    2
y    3
b    4

> mat3
  [,1]
a    -1
b    -2
c    3
d    4
e    5
f    6
x    -1
y    -3

where mat3 <- mat1 - mat2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 #creating your matrices
 mat1<-matrix(1:6,ncol=1,dimnames=list(letters[1:6],NULL))
 mat2<-matrix(1:4,ncol=1,dimnames=list(c("x","a","y","b"),NULL))
 #getting the unique rownames
 rows<-unique(c(rownames(mat1),rownames(mat2)))
 #creating an "empty" mat3
 mat3<-matrix(0,nrow=length(rows),ncol=1,dimnames=list(rows,NULL))
 #filling values
 mat3[rownames(mat1),]<-mat1
 mat3[rownames(mat2),]<-mat3[rownames(mat2),]-mat2
```

Comment: I was planning to use `%in%` function to find common rows, but your solution is nicer...

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to avoid using rownames. Rownames are difficult to manage because one variable (the rowname) is treated differently than the others. This violates the principles of [tidy data](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).

I would use `dplyr::add_rownames()` to convert the rownames to a variable in a dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
```

**data**

```
mat1 <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(letters[1:6]))
mat2 <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(c("x", "a", "y", "b")))
```

convert to data.frame and make variables:

```
d1 <- add_rownames(data.frame(mat1), var = "name")
d2 <- add_rownames(data.frame(mat2), var = "name")
```

merge and compute result:

```
d <- merge(d1, d2, by = "name", all = TRUE)

d %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = sum(mat1, -mat2, na.rm = TRUE))
```